# Disable quick find in SWT table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

How can I **disable** the default quick find behavior in SWT table if something is typed.

It looks like this:

[image: It looks like this]

The related code looks like this:

```
TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(viewerGroup, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
TableViewerColumn keyColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
...
tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
table.setLinesVisible(true);
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
```

Comment: That isn't an SWT feature, must be something the native control used by SWT provides.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is the same behavior in native (gnome) applications. Any suggestions how to suppress it?

Comment: Table doesn't have anything that would change this behaviour.